# Offset Highcharts datalables in donut chart with inner chart

Tags: php, typescript, highcharts, pie-chart, donut-chart

I'm struggling with an issue that is haunting me, and i can't seem to find any fix in the Highcharts documentation.

So i have this Donut Pie Chart, which is showing the amount of money spend on 3 sales channels (B2B, B2C, Normal sale) - That is what the inner circle contains. Then the outer circle contains which type it is (Stock sale or Pre sale) - that indicates how much of the sale is on either type.

The thing is. Whenever any sales channel has no sale on a type (Eg. Stock: 2500 EUR / Pre: 0).
The datalables stack ontop of each other, so it's impossible to make out what's what.

See attached image.

[image: Highcharts donut example]

Then i have function that removes the point, since theres no need to show a 0 on pre or stock.

```
const filterEmptyData = (data: Highcharts.PointOptionsObject[]) => {
   return data.filter(point => point.y !== 0);
};
```

I would like to offset the datalabels from each other to make out what's what.

Here's the code for the Pie chart

```
private async initPieCharts(strCurrencyCode: string, oGraphData: GraphData) {
        const fnFormatter = function () {
            return `${this.point.name}: ${number_format(this.point.percentage, 2)} % <br> Amount: ${number_format(this.point.y, 0)} ${strCurrencyCode}`;
        }

        const filterEmptyData = (data: Highcharts.PointOptionsObject[]) => {
            return data.filter(point => point.y !== 0);
        };

        let arrPies: Highcharts.Chart[] = [];

        let oTurnOverPie = Highcharts.chart(document.getElementById('turnoverPieChart')!, <Highcharts.Options>{
            chart: {
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie',
                backgroundColor: '#FCFCFC',
                height: 436,
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        $('#turnoverPieChart').siblings().highcharts()
                    }
                },
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: oGraphData.oTurnoverGraphData.strTitle,
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Percentage reflects the size of the pie cutout',
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: fnFormatter
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    animation: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#333333',
                        enabled: true,
                        connectorColor: 'black',
                        formatter: fnFormatter,
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [<Highcharts.SeriesPieOptions>{
                name: 'Percentage',
                size: '40%',
                data: filterEmptyData(oGraphData.oTurnoverGraphData.arrData)
            }, <Highcharts.SeriesPieOptions>{
                name: 'OrderType',
                size: '50%',
                innerSize: '80%',
                data: filterEmptyData(oGraphData.oTurnoverGraphData.arrOrderTypeData)
            }],
        });

        arrPies.push(oTurnOverPie);

        let oMarginPie = Highcharts.chart(document.getElementById('marginPieChart')!, <Highcharts.Options>{
            chart: {
                plotShadow: false,
                type: 'pie',
                backgroundColor: '#FCFCFC',
                height: 436,
            },
            navigation: {
                buttonOptions: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: oGraphData.oMarginGraphData.strTitle,
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                }
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Percentage reflects the size of the pie cutout',
                style: {
                    color: '#3F3F3F'
                },
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: fnFormatter
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    animation: false,
                    dataLabels: {
                        color: '#333333',
                        enabled: true,
                        connectorColor: 'black',
                        formatter: fnFormatter,
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [<Highcharts.SeriesPieOptions>{
                name: 'Percentage',
                size: '40%',
                data: filterEmptyData(oGraphData.oMarginGraphData.arrData)
            }, <Highcharts.SeriesPieOptions>{
                name: 'OrderType',
                size: '50%',
                innerSize: '80%',
                data: filterEmptyData(oGraphData.oMarginGraphData.arrOrderTypeData)
            }],
        });

        arrPies.push(oMarginPie);

        initPiePiece(arrPies);
    }
```

Thanks :)

Tried using the distance and padding to offset but it just moves both datalables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've probably tried to place these settings in `plotOptions.series`, which essentially applies the same properties to all series. If you prefer individual settings for each series, you should apply them directly to each of series as follows:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'pie',
  },

  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      distance: 100,
      connectorShape: 'straight',
      connectorPadding: 0,
      padding: 0,
      y: -10
    },
    name: 'Percentage',
    size: '40%',
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 70.67,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 14.77
    }]
  }, {
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      distance: 10,
      connectorPadding: 0,
    },
    name: 'OrderType',
    size: '50%',
    innerSize: '80%',
    data: [{
      name: 'Chrome',
      y: 70.67,
      sliced: true,
      selected: true
    }, {
      name: 'Edge',
      y: 14.77
    }, ]
  }],
});
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3tfboxc8/